# Image taking too long to load?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-layout

EDIT:

After doing a method trace, whenever I switch with the purple square, the graph rises a lot. When I switch with a blue or green circle, it stays low:

[image]

Here are the methods of the swap with the purple square:

[image]

I have an app which swaps two buttons. There is one red button, when it gets clicked, it picks a random button from the other three, and swaps.

I tried doing this one way by just swapping images. In the onClickListener, I only listened for clicks with buttons with the red button.

1. Get random image
2. Make it blank
3. Look for red button
4. Give red button background that random image had (swap)
5. Give random image (which is blank now) red background

If this is confusing...leave it. But:

**Whenever I switch images from a larger image to a smaller image, the process takes a much longer time. It is much faster when swapping between two smaller images. How do I fix this. Is there a certain image size which is optimal for android?**

[image]

Here is the layout code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/813883bce89606d2a82e

As you can see in the image, it takes a much (MUCH!) shorter time swapping background images with the blue circle than the purple square. Why...?

---

---

Why is the way (where I just change the images and check for a button with a red image) slower based on the image sizes? **What image size should I use?**

Thanks so much for your time

Comment: It may well be that what you are trying to do is unreasonable for your device, but it may also be that your implementation is needlessly running in circles to do it (your use of random numbers to terminate a loop bears careful examination).  Put lots of logging into your code and capture logcat output in timestamp mode, or else use the DDMS method tracing and profiling tools, and from that figure out what exactly it is doing and specifically what is taking most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess would be that you have some big PNGs that take a long time to load.

But, we have nice tools to help us actually find out -- so we don't have to guess!

Do a method trace (available in the CPU tab in Android Studio, or the DDMS view in Eclipse+ADT) while doing the switch, and you should see what is taking time.

Comment: Alright, I will check. This is the first time doing a method trace though

Comment: Then it's a wonderful day, because you'll be learning something new! ;)

Comment: Okay, I think i'm getting somewhere. Whenever I switch with the purple square, the graph rises a lot, and with the green or blue circle, the graph only rises a little. Here is an image: http://snag.gy/iScsy.jpg

Comment: Yep. Now, press the little stopwatch button (left of the graph) and try doing one of the "bad" scenarios. When the image shows up, press the stopwatch again. After that, the trace will be fetched, and you should see a trace showing lots of methods, including how long they took.

Comment: And in there, try to find some long-running methods that may be related to what you're doing.

Comment: Alright, so I did that. It seems that it is already sorted out by the longest time at the top and the shortest time at the bottom. I have no idea what these methods are... Here is a screen shot again: http://i.snag.gy/3abvX.jpg

Comment: Okay, so it's the draw that's taking time. Unfortunately, this trace only shows Java-side stuff, and we'd need an OpenGL trace to see details. It is [available in the Android Studio 2.0 Preview](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/11/android-studio-20-preview.html), or in the latest ADT plugin. However, the reasonable guess is that you have a large bitmap (remember, when unpacked, your image is likely 4*width*height bytes in size) -- and it is taking some time to upload to the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

I dont have the exact answer for your question but just 2 recommendations:

1) Make sure you scale the image first before drawing.

2) Using RelativeLayout causes your ViewGroup to measure your children twice instead of one. So Make sure that you dont do any that trigger re-layout on click events

3) I would suggest that you put these View in a GridView or GridLayout and then when you need to swap your views, just swap the positions of your view in an data (Array, for example), and call notifyDataSetChanged();
Hope this help

Comment: What do you mean scale the image...? How do I do that? Also, how do I make sure that I don't trigger re-layout click events...? Thanks

Comment: Using BitmapOption class, here is an guide on this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. If you dont change the size or position of the views then you are not triggering layout.

Comment: What size of image is optimal then?

Comment: Depend on the actual size of the View that you want to display. Usually, you want to scale the image to just a little bigger than your view size.

Comment: Then what do I do if I want my app to be compatible on multiple screen sizes? I have read the android docs...but it is unclear

Comment: Well, you could keep your original image size, store it somewhere (Internal Storage). Just scale it when you need to display. This way if you are on a high resolution device, then image could just be display without scaling.

Comment: What about if I wanted the entire layout to work on different screen sizes? Would I need to create different layouts?

Comment: Yes. Create a different layout. Typically, phone screens can only display 1 column of content, but can be 2 or three on tablet. This link https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/adaptive-ui.html#adaptive-ui-breakpoints has some detail

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the image size can affect the speed. So, what I did was re size my image. I did this in photo shop, but you can do it in `paint` or you can do it in an image-re sizer website. Just search that up in google, and enter the dimentions `56 x 56`. For some reason, those dimensions work best.

Here is one image resizer tool:

http://www.picresize.com/

On this website, just select your image from your computer, and then the next screen will say to resize it:[image]

To do it in `paint`:

[image]

Although the bounty is over, I have just posted this to help people know how to do it. **I STILL DON"T KNOW WHY THE IMAGE SIZE MATTERS** I would really appreciate it if someone explained **why** I must fix the image size, although I know **how**.

Thanks,

NullPointerException