# Can I switch the onClick listeners?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, string

**How do I swap onClick listeners while also being able to know which button is which?**

---

My original problem was:
[Image taking too long to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950685/app-is-responding-very-slowly)

I was trying to delete and re-add views in eachothers places (to swap the two buttons), but the process was very slow. So I decided to try to change the properties of the button, instead of swapping the button itself. This will *require me to keep track of a button AND swap listeners*.

**I have one swap button (the red button). When clicked, it takes one of the other three buttons, and swaps with them. The other three buttons do nothing else.**

Here is my original code (which deletes/re-adds views instead of switching properties):

```
red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {

                // Remove the clicked button from it's frame layout parent.
                    ViewManager p = (ViewManager) v.getParent();
                    p.removeView(v);
                    // Find another button randomly.
                    Random rng = new Random();
                    View v2;
                    do
                    {
                        int i = rng.nextInt(4);
                        v2 = buttons.get(i);
                    }
                    while (v2 == v); // Loop until you get a different button to swap with.
                    // Remove the other button from it's frame layout parent.
                    ViewManager p2 = (ViewManager) v2.getParent();
                    p2.removeView(v2);
                    // Now simply insert each button into the other buttons frame layout.
                    p.addView(v2, v2.getLayoutParams()); //Adding v2, the random button, into where v, the button clicked, was before(p)!
                    p2.addView(v, v.getLayoutParams()); //Adding v, the button clicked, into where v2, the random button, was before(p2)
                }
   }
       });
```

**So, I have two options:**

1. Somehow make the response faster (I don't know how...hence [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950685/app-is-responding-very-slowly))
2. Somehow change the **properties** of the buttons by swapping click listeners and images. AND somehow being able to keep track of the NEW swap button, so that I can swap again.

Thanks so much, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You won't get much attention if your questions contain a lot of reading. I highly suggest reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "*Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence*"

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thanks for your feedback. Have edited to make it shorter.

Comment: @VinceEmigh What should I do to swap the listeners?

Comment: I am not a android dev, so I cannot give you the best solution. I'm also unsure of what you are trying to do (you want to map listeners to buttons, then switch which button has which listener?)

Comment: @VinceEmigh How would I switch which button has which listener? If this is unclear, did you read the linked question? It has some more details. I want to either make the process faster, and if I can't do that, my other option is to somehow change the properties of the buttons by swapping click listeners and images. AND somehow being able to keep track of the NEW swap button, so that I can swap again. Thanks so much!

Comment: I shouldn't have to read the linked question. This question should contain all the information I need to answer this question, which is another reason people may turn away from a question (required to jump through hoops). The smarter users on here have high standards, which you must abide by if you want to attract their attention. I doubt I could answer the question efficiently, although I can attempt to help you format your question better to attract a wider audience. For example, I've reduced the bold, but there's still a lot of bold (in seemingly random places), making it an eye-sore

Comment: People are still upvoting my comment (even after the edits) which shows it's still not up to standards. If you choose to edit again, please do not link to the code - all code should be pasted here, incase a link breaks. How you present the information in the wuestion is important. You told us what you want, then told us what you had, then told us what you want again, showed us what you had again, then again told us what you want... Jumping back and fourth strains cognition

Comment: @VinceEmigh I have edited again, now it is easier to understand without the link. I have still included the link just in case. Hope it's okay now. Thanks

Comment: That's a LOT better :) Hopefully you keep these tactics in mind next time you ask! Thanks for being understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give every single button a listener. Then, in the listener, just check if the background of the button pressed (which should be passed in as a parameter for the onClick) has the background of red.

```
Drawable redBackgroundDrawable = new Drawable(R.drawable.redImage)



public void onClick(View v){



if(v.getBackground == redBackgroundDrawable){

//Execute code

}else{

//We don't care about it!

}

}
```

I found comparing bitmaps is easier than comparing drawables...So you can make redBackgroundDrawable a `bitmapImage`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I have liked and marked your answer best